# Keeping multiple copies Updated to a Template

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vmware

I've not used many tools in either visualization or with Ubuntu itself.  However, I need to solve a problem we will be having very shortly.

We're getting our development team up and running on a new project.  We want our developers to have their own development boxes for running their own services, compiling code, ect.  Each developer would use their own copy of a template.  However, we want to make sure that their copies are updated regularly with configurations and installations that the entire team will need.  We want this to alleviate the concern of "well, the code compiles on MY box".

Right now, we're wanting to use VMWare Workstation or Virtual Box and use the latest stable version of ubuntu.

If this isn't the right place to ask this question, please point me to the correct place, as I'm pretty lost to where I should be asking this question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`cfengine` sounds like the right tool. It's a free download for controlling the configuration (and you get to define what that includes) of up to 25 systems. They sell a product for 26 and up. [Start here](https://cfengine.com/)